# Why does Helm push with "--dependency-update" not find the repository by name but "helm dependency update" does?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a Chart.yaml with the following:

*Chart.yaml*

```yaml
dependencies:
  - name: my-app
    version: "0.1.0"
    repository: "@my-chartmuseum-repo"
```

And I added the repo to helm:

```sh
# helm repo list
NAME                    URL
my-chartmuseum-repo     http://127.0.0.1:8080/
stable                  https://charts.helm.sh/stable
```

When I run `helm dependency update my-owning-app` I get the successful message:

```sh
helm dependency update my-owning-app
Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Successfully got an update from the "my-chartmuseum-repo" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "stable" chart repository
Update Complete. ⎈Happy Helming!⎈
Saving 1 charts
Downloading my-app from repo http://127.0.0.1:8080/
Deleting outdated charts
```

**However**, when I try to do this via `helm push my-owning-app/ my-chartmuseum-repo --dependency-update` I get the error:

```sh
Error: no repository definition for @my-chartmuseum-repo. Please add them via 'helm repo add'
Usage:
  helm push [flags]

Flags:
# ...elided...
```

Why would it work in the first command but not the second one to find the repository by name?

Comment: I am analyzing your issue but would like in the meantime to ask you to try running: `helm push --dependency-update my-chartmuseum-repo my-owning-app/` and tell me what was the outcome.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor That has the repo and directory backwards, so I get this error: `no repo named "my-owning-app/" found`. If I switch those two but leave the dependency flag first, I get the same error as before: `Error: no repository definition for @my-chartmuseum-repo. Please add them via 'helm repo add'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a community wiki answer. Feel free to expand on it.

The `--dependency-update` flag for the `helm push` plugin is currently not working properly due to the fact that it does not omit the `@` symbol when checking the name of the repository.

As a workaround, you could use the [Helm Dependency Update](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_dependency_update/) with a `--repository-config string` flag:

> path to the file containing repository names and URLs (default
> "~/.config/helm/repositories.yaml")